# Completely reset network configuration

Tags: macos, network

I have an AirPort Extreme at home and a MacBook Pro Retina. I've been trying to set up a VPN at home, without any luck. But I'm afraid I broke my network settings along the way... I've tried so many things and tutorials that I honestly have no idea what I did exactly. So there is no way to retrace my steps.

So, for some reason I cannot connect to my AirPort network anymore... Other laptops and iPhones connect just fine, only my MBP doesn't.

What I've tried:

- Reset the AirPort Extreme, no result
- Deleted my Airport and Networdinterfaces .plist in `Macintosh HD/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/`
- Deleted the entire `Macintosh HD/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/` folder
- Boot in Mavericks Recovery HD (with '<kbd>cmd</kbd> + R') and reinstalled Mavericks.

Nothing seem to work...
Funny thing though, when I tried to reinstall Mavericks (in safe mode), I could connect to my network (otherwise I couldn't have downloaded a fresh copy of Mavericks).

So I'm wondering, what else can I reset/do in order to get my network settings up and running?
Or is a clean install the only way to go?

Comment: Does it connect if you boot into safe mode (shift-boot)?

Comment: When booted in safe mode, I could download Mavericks, so yes :)

Comment: You said you booted using cmd-r, which isn't safe mode — it's the Recovery HD. I've edited your question regarding this. Booting with shift is safe mode.

Comment: Ok, I see. I'm unable to test this right now, but I'll do this when I come home. What if I can connect in safe mode?

Comment: Does the IPconfig or the IFconfig work in terminal?

Comment: Yes it does. But I double NAT enabled, so I should get just an internal IP (like 10.0.1.99), but all I get is the local IP (192.168.x.x)...

Comment: @grgarside, yes, in safe mode I can connect to the internet... In fact after going into safe mode, I seemed to be able to connect to the internet. But after a few boots, I'm back to zero... No connection.

Comment: I have a similar issue. Do you by any chance use freedom? The productivity tool that blocks the internet? Or have in the past?